# Parsing file names from a character array

Tags: c++, parsing, char

I apologize if this has been asked before but I am trying to parse an array of characters in away I can obtain filenames.

Here is an example of the character array I end up copying in.

```
picture1.bmp   file2.txt   random.wtf   dance.png
```

Notice that there are 3 spaces between each filename.

I want to do something along the sorts of:

1. Assuming we start at the first character, advance until we reach a space.
2. Copy everything up to that space into an array at index 0.
3. Skip 2 spaces (to traverse the 3 space gap).
4. Go until we hit a space and then copy that into array index 1.

I could do a hack job of this, just curious as to how some of the more advanced programmers would do this as I am here to learn.

Comment: No need to write ` - C++` in the title; we have tags already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::istringstream iss(the_array);
std::string f1, f2, f3, f4;
iss >> f1 >> f2 >> f3 >> f4;
```

Comment: Can you explain more perhaps? How does it know to allow for three spaces between the filenames?

Comment: @PladniusBrooks it skips all spaces (all whitespace actually, including tabs, newlines, etc), be it 1 or 1000

Comment: @Pladinus: The default behavior of `istream::operator>>` on strings is to read whitespace delimited data.  When it comes to any whitespace, it stops reading.  The next call causes it to skip to the next non-whitespace character.  You could have a million spaces, tabs and newlines in there.  They would all be skipped over.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks to you and Seth Carnegie. One last question. I am getting an "incomplete type is not allowed" as the_array is a pointer to character array. How would I make this code work with that?

Comment: @PladniusBrooks: Have you included both `<string>` and `<sstream>`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I had not. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.